# gDoc python API import failure

Tags: python, google-docs

When I try to use gDoc python API following instruction at [python_client_lib](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib#library)

I got below error:

```
In [3]: import gdata
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fc99779d388d> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdata

/Users/e12714/git/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/__init__.py in <module>()
    107 
    108 
--> 109 class LinkFinder(atom.LinkFinder):
    110   """An "interface" providing methods to find link elements
    111 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LinkFinder'
```

What's wrong with me? Any python module missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem.

Issue was due to having atom-0.3.5 installed.

It can be solved by installing pyatom instead of the (optimised, c-implemented) atom

Answer (score 2):

I was able to rectify this issue by removing all traces of atom from my Python installation and installing the latest gdata release (2.0.18) (using setup.py) from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list).

That release includes a version of atom, with the necessary LinkFinder class definition.

It's obviously an issue if you need the separate, more recent atom, in which case you'll have to use virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous recommendations.  I installed the latest version of atom via pip.  That did the trick for me.

```
pip install atom
```