# I am working on getting google contacts using google contacts API . Here I am getting some problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-contacts-api

For running google contacts API, these libraries are used:

```
import atom.data
import gdata.data
import gdata.contacts.client
import gdata.contacts.data
```

The problem is these libraries are not installed correctly.

I am getting these type of errors.

```
1) AttributeError: module 'atom' has no attribute 'LinkFinder'

2) ImportError: No module named core
```

Any solution for doing this importing the libraries correctly?

How to install these library correctly to execute my code?

**EDIT**

I want to know how to remove these errors after installing `atom` and `gdata`.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gDoc python API import failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647064/gdoc-python-api-import-failure)

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Can you explain how to fix these errors after installing `atom` and `gdata`. or give me a way to install these libraries correctly.